# Probability roots of quadratic lie in unit disc

Tags: probability, multivariable-calculus, probability-distributions

$A,B\sim\mathscr{U}(0,1)$ and independent. We consider:

$$x^2+2Ax+B=0$$

> Given that both of the roots of this equation are real, what is the
>   probability that they lie in the unit disc?

**Thoughts:** if $\lambda, \mu$ are the roots then I have found that ${\mathbb{P}(\lambda,\mu \in\mathbb{R})}=1/3$ so by Bayes' law:

$$\mathbb{P}(|\lambda|\leq 1,\; |\mu|\leq 1)=3\cdot\mathbb{P}(\lambda,\mu\in [-1,1])$$
**Update:** following rogerl's suggestion: $\mathbb{P}(\lambda,\mu \in [-1,1])=\mathbb{P}(2A-1-B\leq 0)$.

Set $W=2A-1-B$ and $Z=B$ then the Jacobian is $\frac{1}{2}$ so:

$$f_{W,Z}(w,z)=\frac{1}{2}f_{A,B}(a(w,z),b(w,z))=\frac{1}{2}$$
Then:

$$\mathbb{P}(W\leq 0)=\frac{1}{2}\int_{?}^?\int_?^? dzdw$$
Is this alright? I am stuck on the limits of integration; my thoughts on these were that the unit square in the $A-B$ plane get mapped to the following figure in the $W-Z$ plane:

$\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad$[image]

The region of integration is then the region below the $Z$ axis, which gives $\mathbb{P}(W\leq 0)=3/4.$ This can't be right though, because then the desired probability exceeds $1$. Any help?

Comment: The roots of this equation are $-A \pm \sqrt{A^2-B}$, so you want the probability that both of these numbers have magnitude not exceeding $1$.

Comment: @rogerl Yes I realise this, but I can't see how to find said probability.

Comment: What is intended by the unit disk? Can it mean that the sum of the squares of both roots should be less than 1?

Comment: @anaconda Well, both roots are nonpositive, so all you need to know is whether $-A-\sqrt{A^2-B}$ is greater than $-1$, which happens iff $2A-1 \le B \le A^2$.

Comment: @rogerl Thanks for the help. I've updated the post; still a little stuck on the end.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For your equation $x^2 + 2Ax + B = 0$, the event of the two roots being real is the discriminant should be positive or  $\boxed{A^2 > B}$

In addition, the two roots should lie inside the unit circle so we get two inequalities:

$$  -1 <  -A - \sqrt{A^2 - B} < -A + \sqrt{A^2 - B} < 1$$

In addition, consider $(A,B)$ as a uniformly chosen point of the unit square $[0,1]^2$.  You are trying to find the area outlined by these inequalities.

---

Numerically, I plotted the $A,B$ satisfying your condition.  Your probability is the area of the shape below, roughly **8.4%**

[image]

---

The area under the parabola is $\mathbb{P}[\text{real roots}]=\int_0^1 x^2 \, dx = \frac{1}{3}$ the area of the triangle is $$\mathbb{P}\big[\text{roots }\notin [-1,1] \bigcap \text{real roots}\big]=\frac{1}{2} \times \frac{1}{2} \times 1 = \frac{1}{4}$$  Subtract one from the other $\boxed{\mathbb{P} = \tfrac{1}{3} - \tfrac{1}{4} = \tfrac{1}{12} = 0.083\dots}$

Comment: I can't edit your answer because I only want to add one character - but your answer should be 0.083..., not 0.83...

Comment: Thanks a lot for this; the alternate perspective was very helpful. If possible, could you point out what is wrong with what I had done?